# как скомпилировать с библиотеками pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

скомпилировал проект с одним файлом через pyinstaller -F clicker.py но exe запускается на долю секунды и выводит такой текст, как исправить

```
import keyboard 
import mouse 
import time 

isClicking = False 

def set_clicker():
    global isClicking
    if isClicking:
        isClicking = False 
        print("ВЫКЛ")
    else: 
        isClicking = True
        print("ВКЛ")


keyboard.add_hotkey('Alt + X', set_clicker)

while True:
    if isClicking:
        mouse.double_click(button = 'left')
        time.sleep(0.7)

input("конец")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А библиотека то вообще установлена?

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нет ошибок, необходимо просто установить библиотеки.

1. Откройте командную строку.
2. Введите в консоль:

   ```
   pip install keyboard
   pip install mouse
   ```
3. Готово! Теперь ваша программа работает

Comment: К вашему [комментарию в удаленном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1548186/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-progressbar-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83-tkinter?noredirect=1#comment2787060_1548186): "Нет, вот этот сайт customtkinter.tomschimansky.com. Недавно не работал, уже все хорошо" - это не официальный сайт tkinter, это сайт документации по customtkinter, это отдельная библиотека, у вас в коде она не используется.